# How to write a CSS background tag inside DIV inside PHP-echo statement

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a web site that works a lot with database data but I have a little problem at a section of PHP code that gets an image URL from the database and has to set it as a background resource to a DIV element (a banner in fact).

```
echo "<div class='header-resource' style='background-image: url('article_images/".$image."');'></div>";
```

The communication with the database works flawlessly, the image link actually is inside $image and it works if I try to load the image on a standard IMG element, but it doesn't seem to work on a in my echo statement. Is it because of syntax? Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: use a here doc `echo <<<HTML <div .... \nHTML;` note the ending tag in this case `HTML;` has to be on it's own line no spaces.  This is a way of doing a string without the use of quotes.  So it allows you to use both types of quotes in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Here/Now Doc

```
echo <<<HTML 
<div class="header-resource" style="background-image: url('article_images/{$image}');"></div>
HTML;
```

Note the last `HTML;` tag (can be anything you want) has to be on it's own line nothing else can be on that line, not even space.

Heredoc is a way of doing a quoteless string in many programming languages.  This allows you to use both quotes with no escaping, which simplifies things.

Nowdoc is the same thing but it works like singe quote `'` in that variables are not interpolated (automatically filled in). It's similar syntax is

```
$foo = <<<'TXT'
   Some string
TXT;
```

Notice how it has the single `'` quote, whereas the heredoc does not.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to escape (backslash) the URL:
style='background-image: url('article_images/".$image."');'

*like this:*
style='background-image: url(\'article_images/".$image."\');'

*or this:*
style='background-image: url(/'article_images/".$image."/');'

(need to test... i'm not shure the correct sintax now)